# Firebase Database & Swift: Save location data in an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase-realtime-database

Hi all I am having a hard time saving coordinates in an array on Firebase. Basically I would like to track my location and save the Latitude and Longitude whenever there is a change in location.

This is what I currently get:

```
"-R359orfmkXiwERe948fk" : {
    "coordinates" : {
          "-S6O96394fXd0489fj" : {
            "lat" : Lat1,
            "long" : Long1
          },
          "-S6496SX235Hh12G893sb" : {
            "lat" : lat2,
            "long" : long2
          },
          "-F6O3941SwKZ5cA29038kdsg" : {
            "lat" : lat3,
            "long" : lat3
          },
```

While This is the form I would like to get:

```
"-385fjAhm85fwERe948fk" : {
        "coordinates" : [ [ Lat1,Long1], [Lat 2, Long2], [Lat 2, Long3]]
```

Using Firebase RealTime database and Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase has no native support for arrays.](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

Instead of expecting Firebase to return you an array, I suggest writing a transformation method for your Swift model object, that you can use when you query Firebase, which converts the dictionary you currently receive into an array that you can then utilize throughout your app.

You will need a similar transformation that will then convert your array back to that dictionary format for updating Firebase.

Comment: Is this still true? That firebase does not support arrays?